# How to trim down a URL using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to finish this regex code in PHP.  I want to trim down the following url which is held in variable $text so that it goes from:

```
 http://www.site.net/showthread.php?tid=324&pid=...
```

to:

```
 showthread.php?tid=324
```

Thank you kindly!

Comment: No need to escape the `&`, it has no special meaning. Doesn't PHP have a URL parsing library already?

Comment: So do you want to extract the filename from a URL, or do you have an HTML snippet that contains an anchor from which you would like to extract the href? You have both in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex? The parse_url method should give you all you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Edit: working example

```
$someurl = 'http://www.site.net/showthread.php?tid=324&pid=...';
$urlParts = parse_url($someurl, PHP_URL_PATH | PHP_URL_QUERY);
$params = parse_str($urlParts['query']);
unset($params['pid']);
$queryString = http_build_query($params);
$newUrl = $urlParts['path'] . '?' . $queryString;
```

Since $urlParts['path'] start with a / and you didn't want that, you could even use

```
$newUrl = substr($newUrl, 1);
```

and be done :) Does that help at all?

Comment: Hi, Yes you are right that is an easier solution thank you. However! the Pid doesn't get split out from the tid (that I can see).

Comment: @user1088793 just split the query string on `&`

Comment: @fge and then on =. Plus, that breaks on multi value keys. I really think you don't want to use custom code for situations the built-in functions are suited for.

Comment: Sorry to leech on you guys, but I wonder if you could show me an example on how to do this? I have been reading the guidence on parse-str but struggling to actually implement it for my example.

Comment: Well, parse_str would create a '$_GET-like' array for you, like array('pid' => 123, 'tid' => 324). You can then unset the 'pid' key and use http_build_query to get a new query string. Append that to the part of the url of your choice and voila.

 $params = parse_str($queryString);
 unset($params['pid']);
 $queryString = http_build_query($params);

Comment: ok Pelshoff my brain just exploded ;) I don't understand how to do all of that, so I think I will need to learn some more basics first before going any further.

Comment: I'm sorry :P I posted the code but the formatting won't take. I'll edit it into my answer for you.

Comment: Thats ok, thank you so much for the help very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$url = 'http://www.site.net/showthread.php?tid=324&pid=...';
$pattern = "/showthread.php\?tid=[0-9]+/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $match))
    print_r($match);
```